# find and grep - Suppress terminated by signal 13

Tags: shell, grep, pipe, xargs

If I want to find only first match of command `grep` I use this:

```
find -name "*.jar" | xargs grep -al myText | head -1
```

And it's work just fine.
But it's also show the next message:

```
xargs: grep: terminated by signal 13
```

Is it possible to suppress this message (to not show this message)?

Comment: I guess the message is printed to stderr. In this case, just redirect stderr to /dev/null. BTW, signal 13 is "broken pipe". You find [here](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/courses/moved.Building/signals.pdf) a list of the signals and their meaning. One more remark: `head -1` is obsolete (though still supported for compatibility). The preferred form would be `head -n 1`.

Comment: Suggestion: use `find -exec` or `find -print0 | xargs -0` as a good practice to avoid issues due to filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you have this error message?

-> Signal 13 means a file is unreadable (bad permissions).

2 solutions:

1. Ignore this message (ugly)

- Add `2>/dev/null` after `xargs` command

```bash
find -name "*.jar" | xargs grep -al myText 2>/dev/null | head -1
```

2. Do not try to read unreadable file (better)

- Add a condition `-readable` (readable by current user) to `find` command

```bash
find -name "*.jar" -readable | xargs grep -al myText | head -1
```

### Note:

You could display unreadable files with this command:

```bash
find \! -readable
```